# Stacked point representation in KMLs 

Tags: kml, point, google-earth

I cross posted this in the Google Earth forum but they changed the format there and I'm not sure I like the format.

In my dataset I sometimes have multiple locations at a single point.

GE will represent this as a single dot until you click on the dot and then you get a scattering of all the points at that location.

Is there anyway to script into the KML a sizing on the initial dot viewed to represent how many dots are on that location? (ex. 1-3 small dot, 4-6 med dot, 7-9 large dot)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Create Proportional Symbols for the number of dots. You need to do some modification to suit your needs.

[image]

Use the Thematic Mapping API

http://thematicmapping.org/

Comment: I will check this out...so, in theory, the large dot, when clicked, would scatter out to it's appropriate number of individual dots?

Comment: Not sure if this fits the bill - this seems that it would require a piece of information, a "count" field, to read in order to know the number of dots at a location.  These are all individual locations with different information for each point.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the output of the KML then you should run some clustering and detect such overlaps and cluster (group) the icons together and assign an appropriate style (e.g. style_cluster_6  vs style_cluster_15) based on number of overlapping icons.  Then the detail on each placemark could list out all of the items that have been grouped together.  Otherwise I think you're looking at writing a GE extension.

Note that you may want to cluster things even if they aren't right on top of each but close enough either by a real distance or pixel distance at certain zoom level.

Comment: Hi Vadim - what do you mean by "run some clustering"? 

Google Earth is already determining the clustering and grouping and I just want to work off of that.  I'm not a programmer (and believe me I've tried over the years) so I'm looking for something within the scripting constraints of KML.

Comment: I see, so you're already working with a KML file and you're just trying to improve how it looks.  I don't believe there's a way (setting or code) in KML to tell "hey, google earth, when you see X overlapping icons, can you please put a big fat circle in their place".  What I was talking about is when the data is extracted from database (for example) to form that KML file it could be clustered to produce a meta-point that represents multiple points.

Comment: Vadim - yes, I'm mostly trying to improve the look.  I think writing something to do what is essentially zoom levels for points is beyond my abilities. 

Thanks for the suggestions.